# Undefined reference and .so files?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I'm pretty new to c++ but i am getting along with programming pretty well.

Now i wanted to add Some commands from an API i downloaded and i got some problems.

So I Included all header Files and added every library possible in Code::Blocks.

[Screenshot of the headers and libs from the API I downloaded:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqXB3.png)

So now I want to call one of the functions provided by the API and when i get a linker error saying

```
    .../binacpp.so: File not recognized : Fileformat not recognized
```

If i am not worng the binacpp.so library should contain my function pre-compiled.

Now i understand that .so files for linux are Dynamic librarys and not static librarys.

So i got into google and some forums said i should include it into the systems dynamic librarys and get it into " LD_LIBRARY_PATH" But i'm pretty new to linux ( i only got Raspian for my Raspberry Pi 3) And  don't really know how to get this done...

I tried out what is on the net but nothing did really work.

Like i said i'm pretty new to coding and linux so if some of you guys can give me some advice i would be pretty grateful.

I'll share the link to the API i wanna use here:

https://github.com/binance-exchange/binacpp

Also: In the readme.txt there is something about "exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH and run like this" but nothing of this really tells me anything

Thanks in advance for your advice

sincerly AD

Comment: Are you trying to say you downloaded the library rather than building it locally? If so, your local platform needs to match the platform the library was compiled for.

Comment: Also, please don't post screenshots of explorer windows when the only information you're trying to convey is a textual list of filenames.

Comment: It seems you are trying to use the provided `libbinacpp.so`. But we aware that it may have been compiled with a different target (e.g. 64 bits instead of 32). Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) about libraries issues.

Comment: ok in the readme there is written i need to run make to get the libraries again. 

Now i get the error, that the function _to_string () _ is ambigous.any idea?